# VBA Recordset Update - Invalid Argument - Work Except One Record

Tags: ms-access, vba

Okay, so the overall goal is to get data from an Excel file into a SharePoint list. I have imported the Excel file into a temp table (Payroll Link), I have a source recordset (records which need adding to the SharePoint List) and a destination recordset (the SharePoint list).

The code below works great and has just loaded 14,577 records successfully. However, it doesn't like the one record!!! I get "Invalid argument". The record I am trying to append looks the same as the others, it isn't a duplicate and the data types of the SharePoint fields are Short Text with no restrictions. What have I missed?!?!?

```
Sub Example()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim Source_rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Dest_rst As DAO.Recordset

Set Source_rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Payroll Link].REFNO, [Payroll Link].CDSID, [Payroll Link].INITS, [Payroll Link].SURNAME, [Payroll Link].[C/CENT], [Payroll Link].GRADE FROM [Payroll Link] LEFT JOIN [Payroll Data] ON [Payroll Link].REFNO = [Payroll Data].[Payroll Number] WHERE ((([Payroll Link].REFNO) Is Not Null) AND (([Payroll Data].[Payroll Number]) Is Null));", dbOpenDynaset)
Set Dest_rst = db.OpenRecordset("Payroll Data", dbOpenDynaset)

With Source_rst
     If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
         .MoveLast
         .MoveFirst
         While (Not .EOF)
             Dest_rst.AddNew
             Dest_rst![Payroll Number] = Trim(Source_rst![REFNO])
             Dest_rst![CDS ID] = Trim(Source_rst![CDSID])
             Dest_rst![Initials] = Trim(Source_rst![INITS])
             Dest_rst![SURNAME] = Trim(Source_rst![SURNAME])
             Dest_rst![Cost Centre] = Trim(Source_rst![C/CENT])
             Dest_rst![GRADE] = Trim(Source_rst![GRADE])
             Dest_rst.Update
             .MoveNext
             DoEvents
         Wend
     End If
     .Close
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, the SharePoint list has no problems with me entering exactly the same data manually?!

Comment: Well, _some_ difference there is. We don't have your table, so you must debug this yourself.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, the code isn't error-ing because it doesn't fancy it. What I need help with is suggestions on what to check. I have checked the obvious stuff and now I am out of ideas!

Comment: Examine the length of the trimmed values. If a tab, null char, cr, and/or lf is included, the length will be larger than it might seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! There was a special character hiding in one of the fields (in my case a file separator character). I found this by checking the ASCII values of every character using the Asc() function in VBA.

Changing:

```
Dest_rst![Initials] = Trim(Source_rst![INITS])
```

To:

```
Dest_rst![Initials] = Trim(Replace(Source_rst![INITS], Chr(28), ""))
```

fixed it for me.